# Separation of delayed mixtures of signals

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have three emitters in three different positions that emit three signals `S1(t)`, `S2(t)` and `S3(t)` with:

```
S1(t) = S2(t) = S3(t)
```

Two receivers receive `R1(t)` and `R2(t)` with:

```
R1(t) = r1(t-D1) + r2(t-D2) + r3(t-D3) 
R2(t) = r1(t-D1) + r2(t-D2) + r3(t-D3)
```

```
r(t) = conv(S(t),Imp_r)
```

`Imp_r` is a realization of the channel impulse response.

My goal is to separate `R(t)` and get `r1(t-D1)`, `r2(t-D2)`, `r3(t-D3)` with the exact delays. ICA and SCA methods work only on instantaneous mixtures, in this case we have delayed mixtures. Is there any other method to solve this problem?

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Comment: will you solve the problem if there were only two signals and two time delays?

Comment: Let's suppose we have only two emitters which means only two signals with two time delays. How can you solve it ?